# JSON Serialization of Type

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5, system.text.json

I'm trying to serialize an object that has a `Type` property into JSON. By default this isn't allowed due to security concerns, so I'm wondering if it's possible with an explicit converter (or if it's not even a good idea).

Here is the converter I wrote based on what I got from [this MSDN tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#sample-basic-converter). It uses [`Type.GetType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=net-6.0#System_Type_GetType_System_String_) to try to convert any type in two of my own assemblies (neither of which contains this class).

```cs
    internal class TypeConverter : JsonConverter<Type>
    {
        public override Type Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            string s = reader.GetString();
            return Type.GetType($"{s}, {nameof(MyAssembly1)}", throwOnError: false)
                ?? Type.GetType($"{s}, {nameof(MyAssembly2)}");
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Type value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

My test code executes and produces the appropriate JSON, but on deserialization the `Type` property is `null`.

Is what I am trying to do possible/recommended? If so, how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Why not use a factory instead? you'll serialize just a key, that it is used to generate the related type. I imagine you won't have to de/serialize every kind of object.

Comment: Your `JsonConverter` looks OK. Most likely you have issues with getting a type using `Type.GetType($"{s}, {nameof(MyAssembly1)}"`. Check this part